# Query annotation not working with and / or operators

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I'm trying to create custom MongoDB queries in Java with Spring

A simple query, like this, works fine

```
@Query("{'status' : ?0}")
Page<Project> filterProjects(String status, Pageable pageable);
```

But when I try a more complicated query with $and and $or, I don't get back any results

```
@Query(value = "{ '$and' : [ { '$or' : [ { 'project_title': {$regex:?0,$options:'i'}}, { 'project_description': {$regex:?0,$options:'i'}}, { 'project_short_name': {$regex:?0,$options:'i'}}]}, { 'status' : ?1}, { 'assignee' : ?2} ]}")
Page<Project> filterProjects(String search, String status, String assignee, Pageable pageable);
```

The raw mongodb query version of the above works fine

```
  db.project.find( {
        $and: [
            { $or: [ { 'project_title': {$regex: <search> ,$options:'i'}}, { 'project_description': {$regex: <search>,$options:'i'}}, { 'project_short_name': {$regex:<search>,$options:'i'}}]},
            { 'status' : <status>},
            { 'assignee' : <assignee>}
        ]
    } )
```

Is there something wrong with the query in @Query or are these operations not supported at all, in @Query?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried out removing the single quotes ('') around `$and`/`$or` in the value of your `@Query` annotation ?